# extend messagebox in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs4, messagebox, extjs-mvc

i created a new view class that extends ext.window.messagebox
but when i try to show it, it gives me an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setVisible' of null
```

my code :

```
Ext.define('view.forms.MyBox', {
extend : 'Ext.window.MessageBox',
alias : 'widget.info',
xtype : 'forms-info',

resizable : false,  
//closable : false --> removed 
layout : 'vbox',
padding : 5,
width : 400,
height : 160,

showMessage: function() {

    console.log('show message')

    var me = this;

    me.show({           
        title: 'Title foo!',
        msg: 'test',
closable : false, // added here
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,            
    });     
}
}); //eoc myBox
```

what are the possible causes of this?

Comment: I suppose you need to add this : `this.callParent(arguments)`

Comment: Please attach full code

Comment: ok, i manage to solve this by removing closable:false config and added it to me.show() function... but i still dont understand why? i updated my code...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've misspelled "closeable" - you have it as "closable".

EDIT: Sorry - this is not correct. I've removed the example.

Comment: i think it is not correct, you've probably removed the error, but the actual spelling in the api is 'closable' not 'closeable'. Still, the 'close tool' appears.

Answer (score 0):

where did u create instance of message?

I think You need to do this after your code..

```
var win = Ext.create('iportfolio.lib.view.forms.MyBox',{});
```

`win.show();`

I hope this will help you.